# Unable to download Image from URL Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, download, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin app which retrives info from DB, take/choose photo and upload them to remote server, display this images from the remote server and the user can delete them by tap on and press a button. The final step is to download the images stored in the server to the local device gallery.

This is my current button click event:

```
private void button_download_image_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Uri image_url_format = new Uri(image_url);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        try
        {              
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(image_url_format);
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += webClient_DownloadDataCompleted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
}
```

Below the `webClient_DownloadDataCompleted` method:

```
private void webClient_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Uri image_url_format = new Uri(image_url);
        byte[] bytes_image = e.Result;
        Stream image_stream = new MemoryStream(bytes_image);
        string dest_folder= Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString();
        string file_name= Path.GetFileName(image_url_format.LocalPath);
        string dest_path= Path.Combine(dest_folder, file_name);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dest_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
              image_stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
              DisplayAlert("Alert", "Download completed!", "OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }
}
```

But it does not work, no error caught, I get the alert which warn me that the download is completed. Also I gave permission for **internet**, **write_external_storage** and **read_external_storage**.

Another thing is that the images after some time, appears in the gallery under **Download** album which is correct.

Any idea about this behavior?

**EDIT**

Below my new button download event:

```
private void button_download_image_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Uri image_url_format = new Uri(image_url);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes_image = webClient.DownloadData(image_url_format);
        Stream image_stream = new MemoryStream(bytes_image);
        string dest_folder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString();
        string file_name = Path.GetFileName(image_url_format.LocalPath);
        string dest_path = Path.Combine(dest_folder, file_name);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dest_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            image_stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }
    DisplayAlert("Alert", "File scaricato con successo", "OK");
}
```

Comment: Since your image appears in the gallery it seems as if it actually **was** downloaded. Please describe more thoroughly what the expected behavior is, b/c it's not really clear from what you've written.

Comment: @PaulKertscher The expected behavior is: push on download button -> the image will save in **Downloads** folder in the device. Everything goes well but the image does not appear in the folder, also in the gallery.

Comment: Did you check with the file explorer that it indeed does not exist. It may be that for some reason the Gallery does not refresh properly.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Yes, I check with the file explorer without success. A strange thing is that when I connect to my home's wifi, I can see the image in the gallery, is it only a coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image was downloaded correctly and I can see it in my file explorer.

I resolved my problem with a resfresh of the gallery, with this lines after saving my image, so the method will be:

```
private void button_download_image_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri image_url_format = new Uri(image_url);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes_image = webClient.DownloadData(image_url_format);
        Stream image_stream = new MemoryStream(bytes_image);
        string dest_folder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString();
        string file_name = Path.GetFileName(image_url_format.LocalPath);
        string dest_path = Path.Combine(dest_folder, file_name);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dest_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            image_stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
        // this 3 lines fix my problem
        var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
        mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(dest_path)));
        Android.App.Application.Context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }
    DisplayAlert("Alert", "File scaricato con successo", "OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Causes**

Your function "fires and forget" about the download and then directly shows you the "Download complete" popup. The reaons are that you are calling **asynchronous** functions in a synchronous way (`DownloadDataAsync`)... This is why it would still appear after a while in the gallery while you still get the pop up.

**Solutions**

You should first read that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Then as a starting point, try with declaring your event handler async and use the await keyword at appropriate places:

```
private async void button_download_image_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri image_url_format = new Uri(image_url);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    try
    {            
        await webClient.DownloadDataAsync(image_url_format); // This will await the download
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course it would be better to also refactor the other method using the async/await pattern all the way down, but this gives you a good starting point I guess.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the new method you edited, try using `DownloadDataTaskAsync`and `CopyToAsync` method along with async/await pattern:

```
 private async void  button_download_image_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Uri image_url_format = new Uri("url");
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes_image = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(image_url_format);
            Stream image_stream = new MemoryStream(bytes_image);
            string dest_folder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString();
            string file_name = Path.GetFileName(image_url_format.LocalPath);
            string dest_path = Path.Combine(dest_folder, file_name);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dest_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await image_stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           await DisplayAlertAsync("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
        await DisplayAlertAsync("Alert", "File scaricato con successo", "OK");
    }
```

Also, you should create a `DisplayAlertAsync` method and call it the same way using await.

Happy coding!

Comment: Tried, but return error when adding await to **DownloadDataAsync**. I add the edited download method.

Comment: @LeonardoBassi This is a starting point then. Read the exception message carefully and try to fix your code accordingly.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Now I can see the image in file explorer, but not in the gallery.

Comment: @LeonardoBassi Did that help you? If so could you mark it as answer so it helps other people having the same case. Cheers.