# Exception "The URI prefix is not recognized" from WebClient.DownloadDataAsync

Tags: android, ios, image, xamarin.forms, system.io.file

I was trying to save an image from an URL and I have an inner exception inside an inner exception tellin the URi prefix is not recognized.

Full exception:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. 
Check InnerException for exception details. ---> 
    System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. --->
         System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

Some code:

```
imagen_tap.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("URL IMAGE BRO::::::::: " + imagen.Source.ToString());
   await api.DownloadImage(new Uri(imagen.Source.ToString()));
   string path = Preferences.Get("filePath", "");
   await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest { File = new ReadOnlyFile(path) });
};


public async Task DownloadImage(Uri URL)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            string folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Images", "temp");
            string fileName = URL.ToString().Split('/').Last();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, e.Result); //Broken?
            };

            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(URL);

            Preferences.Set("filePath", filePath);
        }
```

EDIT: (forgot to add this)
(NOT REAL URL)
The URL is https://api.com/imagenes/partes/18005/2021062311191329243400.jpg

EDIT: (answering Jason, making sure if URL is correct on webClient)

[Screenshot URI on webClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhTP.png)

[Screenshot Opening localstorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e88Oo.png)

[Screenshot Broken Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXLqA.png)

[Screenshot e in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCDHD.png)

EDIT:

Well... I fixed the Uri prefix...

I changed 2 things:
In the Download Image I changed it from Task to string and returning a string.
Code:

```
public string DownloadImageString(string URL)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            string folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Images", "temp");
            string fileName = URL.ToString().Split('/').Last();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, e.Result);
            };

            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(URL));

            return filePath;
        }
```

And then I changed the way I was sending the URL.

Instead of sending a new Uri(url)
I'm sending a string.
That string is mounted manually again, not by taking imagen.Source (this was the real fix)
Code:

```
Image imagen = new Image
                {
                    Source = url + Foto.ID_Parte + "/" + Foto.Archivo
                };
                var imagen_tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                imagen_tap.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
                {
                    string path = api.DownloadImageString(url + Foto.ID_Parte + "/" + Foto.Archivo);
                    await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest { File = new ReadOnlyFile(path) });
                };
                
                imagen.GestureRecognizers.Add(imagen_tap);
```

Comment: If you have questions please put them in your post.

Comment: And tell which uri prefix.

Comment: "The URI prefix is not recognized." seems like a pretty clear message.  What is the URI you are trying to download?

Comment: Edited question, I actually forgot to post the URL

Comment: are you **sure** that is actually the url being passed to the webclient?  Based on your code it appears that you are trying to extract the url from an ImageSource, which will not work

Comment: Edited question with debug.

Comment: which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: The one with the //Broken? Edited question, adding screenshot

Comment: Then it seems the problem isn't the URL you tried to download. Given that code made it to `DownloadDataCompleted `. The obvious next question: Value of "filePath" just before `File.WriteAllBytes? And what is value of e.Result?

Comment: Added screenshot, e is giving problems.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake then. I incorrectly thought that when DownloadDataCompleted was reached, we were past the possibility of a problem in the WebRequest. Didn't occur to me that if there was a failure, it would be in the Result. Its very strange that you got prefix error on what looks like a normal prefix (https://)...

Comment: BTW, you'll want `await` at front of line `webClient.DownloadDataAsync(URL);`. Won't fix this problem, but avoids blocking thread during download.

Comment: I've tried but i't gives me error, Cannot be used with Void. https://prnt.sc/1dzcxey
I could do await Task.Run(() =>
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(URL)
            );

Comment: I can't think of any cause, except something being strange in that URI string. I recommend testing with a hardcoded URL string, that is known to be valid. E.g. one of the images you just posted, such as `Uri = new Uri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhTP.png"`. Same error message?

Comment: Strange... with HardCoded Uri i get System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.companyname.workersapp/files/Images/temp/oXhTP.png"' But with the real Uri i get the other error...

Comment: Try to use `byte[] bytes_image = webClient.DownloadData(URL);` directly to see if it returns data ,refer to the sample here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/60090843/8187800.

Comment: It explodes saying: System.NotSupportedException: 'WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the fix works, I was testing in the phone now and it works correctly, the fix is in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

bro you dont need to manage lazy loading and local storage of image manually just use library [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/FFImageLoading) for it , it will save your time and boost your app performance

this Library loads images quickly & easily on Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms

confirm me if this answer is working for you or not!

Comment: The thing is, This post is a TRY to solve another post xD I want to open an image on default gallery APP on Android/IOS And someone told me to use a function. But that function only works with local images, so I thought: Download image and open it... Post is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437194